# Method Decorators - Need the fully qualified path of the class module calling the decorator

Tags: typescript

When the decorator (method decorators) function is executed, we get access to `target`, `methodName` and `descriptor`.

I want to know the module path for `target` in this case. So basically the file path that leads to the module that called the decorator. How do I get this information?

I tried using the `module` object, ie `module.parent.filename`, but that one isn't safe to use as it doesn't update when the same decorator is used in another file - so it stores the information of the file where the decorator was first called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the [callsites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/callsites) package to help me determine where the call is coming from. I just filter through it with my desired query and get back the proper path.

Something like this:

```
const myPath: string = callsites()
  .find(f => f.getFileName().includes('myquery'))
  .getFileName();
```

Pretty simple. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the [Reflect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) API? If so, I believe you'll have to first store the module info for the class target as metadata in a class decorator. Then you can retrieve it in your method decorator.

**EDIT**:

My solution ended up slightly more convoluted than I would like; I forgot that method decorators are evaluated *before* class decorators, so we need a workaround for that.

**decorators.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";

export function InjectModuleInfo (filename: string) {
    return function <T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }> (constructor: T) {
        Reflect.defineMetadata("modulePath", filename, constructor);
    }
}

export function MyMethodDecorator (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata("modulePath", target.constructor));
}
```

**TestClass.ts**

```
import {MyClassDecorator, MyMethodDecorator} from './decorators';

@InjectModuleInfo(__filename)
class BaseClass {}

export class TestClass extends BaseClass {
    @MyMethodDecorator
    public myMethod () {}
}
```

Each class you want to support this will need to inherit from a base class which has the module info attached as metadata. Otherwise as I mentioned, if you place the decorator directly on `TestClass`, the class decorator will not have been evaluated in time for the method decorator.

Comment: I have that already included in my project! How do I do what you said exactly?

Comment: Thanks, but this solution creates a massive inconvenience for me. I appreciate your input though!

Comment: This approach doesn't work to me. I used stack trace of Error class.